# Elasticsearch will not auto start on reboot on my ELK instance

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I have an ELK setup on a single instance running ubuntu 18.04. Every service (logstash, kibana, metricbeat) will auto start upon reboot except elasticsearch. I have to issue `sudo service elasticsearch start` command after rebooting the instance.

I tried this command `sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch enable` but it did not help.

What needs to be done to so that elastic would restart automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in ubuntu 18.04 (above 16.04) the `systemctl` is command control of `systemd`.
to making a program as service you should use below command:

```
systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```

you can check a program is service enabled?

```
systemctl is-enabled elasticsearch.service
```